# test-unit gem displays test stat for every rake run

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I using test-unit gem with a Rails 3.1 project, and I have a small issue. If I start rake tasks, I always see a test result, with zeros.

My Gemfile is:

```
source :rubygems

gem 'rails', '3.1.2'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'json_pure'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
#  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5.rc.2'
#  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Rails i18n
gem 'rails-i18n', :git => 'git://github.com/hron84/rails-i18n.git'

# Paginator

gem 'will_paginate'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
gem 'thin'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

group :development do
  gem 'rails3-generators'
  gem 'nifty-generators'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'ci_reporter'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  unless defined? Rubinius
    gem 'rcov'
    gem 'rcov_rails'
    gem 'test-unit'
  end
  gem 'ruby-prof'
  gem 'faker'
end

# Application-related stuffs

gem 'authlogic'

# Slug helper
gem 'slug'

# vim: ft=Gemfile
```

Is there a way to avoid it? What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check your RAILS_ENV.  Make sure it's set to "development", not "test".  If that's not the culprit, try removing gems (particularly test/spec-related ones) one by one until the problem goes away.  Then you'll know which gem is giving you the problem.

Comment: It is set to development. I tried remove all gems, but test-unit, the problem is still here. After removing test-unit, the problem is gone. But i dont want to remove test-unit gem.